# manually resizable and overlay square in the screen with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, pub.dev

hi I'm trying to make a widget like the one in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pmO4.jpg)"(green one) with flutter , the main function is being resizable and overlaying.
is there any idea to achieve this ?
thanks

Comment: You forgot the image 

Comment: you can use stack widget to overlay

Comment: @LuisUtrera it's up there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a pretty good package witch satisfy my needs ,at least for one part of my question.
here is a link :https://github.com/zamaniafshar/Flutter-Resizable-Widget.git